# capture window text

Tags: capture

I'm trying to capture yahoo and msn messenger conversation text, and no tool is able to do it.
Any idea how it can be done without sniffing packets?

Comment: Errr... they both have message logging. Can't you just log your conversations? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: programming language? operating system? yahoo / msn client?
maybe a reason why you'd wanted to do this...? if you want some information, provide some as well. however... if you're using pidgin on linux, you possible could do something with the D-Bus-plugin. vote for close as not real question. regards

Comment: C#. I need to log all the conversations that other users do on this PC.

Answer (score 0):

With Live Messenger's history feature enabled, you can read the text right from the history files stored as XML.